# I want the original case-sensitve tagName in XML element.

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The following code returns UpperCase text of the tagName. I want the original case.

```
var xml = '<myElements type="AA" coID="A923"><myHouse>01</myHouse> <myCars>02</myCars><myWifeAndDog>03</myWifeAndDog></myElements>';

$(xml).children().each(function () {
    var xmlnode = $(this);
    console.log(this.tagName + " - " + xmlnode.text());
});
```

Returns:

```
MYHOUSE - 01
MYCARS - 02
MYWIFEANDDOG - 03
```

**I want it to return:**

```
myHouse - 01
myCars- 02
myWifeAndDog- 03
```

**How can i do this?**

**SOLVED:** Using DOM as Mike suggested. Not sure if this is supported by ALL browsers though.

```
var xmlDoc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data.xmltext, "text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(data.xmltext);
}
console.log(xmlDoc);
console.log(xmlDoc.firstChild.children[0].tagName);
```

Comment: pretty sure you cant.  One thing you can do though is make a displayName attribute and use `this.getAttribute("displayname")`

Comment: @Joseph: I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you shouldn't use jQuery for that and use the DOM like:

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlStr = '<myElements type="A" coID="A92"><myHouse>1</myHouse></myElements>',
    dom = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    console.log(dom.firstChild.tagName);
```

This is ok for Firefox, Chrome.
IE has another way to read and load XML, but similar in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) before passing the xml to the `$()` function.

```
var $xml = $.parseXML(xml);

$('myElements > *', $xml).each(function(){
    var xmlnode = $(this);
    console.log(this.tagName+" - "+xmlnode.text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97a7T/

Answer (score 0):

when you use `.tagName` on an `HTML` tag it will always return you the tagname in upper case where as when you use `.tagName` on the `XML` node the case is preserved

here is the reference http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName

they say that in opera the case is preserved on HTML tags, you can try it ...

Comment: I saw the reference... i'm using it on an XML node and it's not preserving case... so what would the correct syntax be?

Comment: it seems that jquery doesn't treat the `xml` string as `XML`